# jQuery issue with anchor tag using jqTransform

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jqtransform on my site.  When the user is on a  for them to be able to use hot keys to move through the selections.  I added this function:

```
$wrapper.find('a').keydown(function (e) {

            var Esc = 27;

            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

            if(code== Esc || (code>=65 &&code<=90)){
                var letter = String.fromCharCode(code);

                if (code==Esc)
                    keyCodes = "";
                else{

                    if (keyCodes=='')
                        keyCodes += letter;
                    else
                        keyCodes += letter.toLowerCase();



                    var item = $wrapper.find('a[text^=\'' + keyCodes + '\']:first');

                    item.click();
                }
            }
        });
```

inside of $.fn.jqTransSelect.

This code works fine in all browsers but IE.  the only thing i can find is that IE doesn't like the click event.  Can anyone please help me with this?

If i debug into the code I can see that item is a select not an anchor like i would expect it to be, and that confuses me even more.

Comment: Have you tried changing the value instead?

Comment: I have tried item.change, $(item).click, and $(item).change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that IE do not execute `$('a[text^=\'' + keyCodes + '\']:first')` selector properly

take a closer look at [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). There are some variations of contains selector at comments.

I use regexcontains selector

```
$.expr[':'].regexcontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '').search(new RegExp(meta[3], "ig")) >= 0;
```

as

```
var item = $wrapper.find("a:regexcontains('^" + keyCodes + "'):first");
```